# How to customize font color via CSS for Hestia?

Tags: css

I'm trying to customize some of the font colors for the Hestia theme. The section subtitles and card descriptions are #999999, which is very hard to read on a white background.

In the Features section, for example, I've tried inserting:

```
.hestia-features .description {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.hestia-features .hestia-features-content .feature-box p {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

to no avail. Any thoughts?

Here are examples of the HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 hestia-features-title-area"> <h2 class="hestia-title">Title</h2><h5 class="description">This text needs to be black instead of gray</h5> </div>
```

or

```
<div class="hestia-info"> <a href="#"> <div class="icon" style="color:#180de2"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> </div> <h4 class="info-title">Title</h4> </a> <p>This text needs to be black</p> </div>
```

Comment: did you try to add `!important` argument ?

Comment: Just tried this but it doesn't resolve the issue unfortunately

Comment: Can you share html part where you want to change ? Do you see your css adding in tool ? when you inspect ?

Comment: Yes, see the edit above

Comment: Here we dont see any div with class `hestia-features`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the [working demo](https://demo.themeisle.com/hestia/) the first selector should be:

```
section.hestia-features h5.description {
   color: #000000;
   font-size: 18px;
}
```

And the second should be:

```
section.hestia-features .hestia-info p {
   color: #000000;
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

If you are using Wordpress one more suggestion I have is to check if the theme is using a cache plugin. If it does make sure to delete the cache.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added these lines of code, but the text color hasn't changed. I also double checked and there are no caching plugins running in WP.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a URL to that page? A working demo of the theme would do fine if it includes your elements.

Comment: Here's a demo of Hestia which includes the above elements (and you can see how difficult it is to read some of the light gray text on a white background): https://demo.themeisle.com/hestia/

Comment: @Mark I updated my answer. One helpful tool that will save you tons of time in the future is the Dev Tools. More specifically the inspector, with the inspector you can check how the elements are targeted. My answer will work only if your CSS is loaded after the theme's CSS, which is probably the case.